# How to put the image files I scraped using Beautiful soup into a list?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, reddit

This is the code I used to take all the pics from r/pics on reddit and put it into a directory. I want to be able to take the actual files in the directory and put it into a list. Stuck on how to do this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os

url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = bs(data,'lxml')

image_tags = soup.findAll('img')

if not os.path.exists('direct'):
    os.makedirs('direct')

os.chdir('direct')
x = 0

for image in image_tags:
    try:
        url = image['src']
        source = requests.get(url)
        if source.status_code == 200:
            img_path = 'direct-' + str(x) +'.jpg'
            with open(img_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(requests.get(url).content)
                f.close()
                x+=1
    except:
        pass
```

Edit: Here is updated code but still dealing with problem

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os


url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/drawing"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = bs(data,'lxml')

image_tags = soup.findAll('img')

if not os.path.exists('directory'):
    os.makedirs('directory')

os.chdir('directory')
x = 0
mylist = []
for image in image_tags:
    url = image['src']
    source = requests.get(url)
    if source.status_code == 200:
        img_path = 'direct-' + str(x) +'.jpg'
        with open(img_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(url).content)
            mylist.append(img_path)
            f.close()
            x += 1


print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

create a list in the beginning of your code:

```
...
mylist = []
...
```

then after you get each image, add it to the list

```
...
img_path = 'direct-' + str(x) +'.jpg'
mylist.append(img_path)
....
```

EDIT:

I executed your updated code and the `image_tags` is returning empty - in fact the page returned by

```
url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/drawing"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
```

Doesn't contain any images. I guess reddit has some kind of protection to prevent you from fetching images this way.

Try adding `print(data)` and you will see what I mean

You should use the [reddit api](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/) so that reddit doesn't limit your requests.

Comment: Ok so I put mylist = [] before the for loop.  And then I append the img_path to mylist under my "with open(img_path, 'wb') as f:". But once I ask to print(mylist) I still just get an empty list : "[]". any ideas why?

Comment: @AliHalawa seems solid.

Comment: @AliHalawa Also, remove the useless `try/except` - it is hiding the errors in your code, very hard to write code when errors get silenced and you can't easily know what is wrong from the error messages.

Comment: Ok I removed it but I still don't get any errors, and mylist remains empty

Comment: @AliHalawa please edit the question and add your updated code to the end. If you get empty list maybe the status_code is not 200, that would cause the `append()` part to never execute because of the `if`

Comment: Or maybe `image_tags` is empty

Comment: I think the status code is 200 because my directory is filled with images

Comment: @AliHalawa if it worked before, it is not working anymore - but I think reddit it is that is blocking you, not your code. Check your response, it doesn't contain any images. Delete the images you have and see if they will redownload

Comment: Could it be the placement of mylist.append(img_path). Because when I put it where I have in the code above, it doesnt scrape any images but when I remove it then it does work

Comment: @AliHalawa not related - reddit is definitely blocking you. It works sometimes and fails sometimes because the response you're getting from reddit is not consistent.

Comment: I see, I guess I will probably need to find an alternative image scraping tool. Thank you for all the effort :)

Comment: @AliHalawa the problem is not the tool - reddit website doesn't allow directly scrapping their contents, and will try to stop you - it is better to use their api which is the method they created and support to allow this kind of content extracting.